# Perl 6: Difference between .. and ...?

Tags: raku

What's the difference between .. and ... in Perl 6?

For example, the following lines will produce the same output:

```
for 1..5 { .say };

for 1...5 { .say };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl double-dot range operator .. vs triple-dot ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933615/perl-double-dot-range-operator-vs-triple-dot)

Comment: That question refers to Perl 5, which is basically a different language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`..` construct a range object (think mathematical interval).

`...` constructs a sequence (think lazily generated one-shot list).

If all I want to do is iterate over consecutive integers (eg for indexing), I prefer he former (it's the less general tool, and a character shorter to boot).

If you need more precise control, use the latter (eg the idiomatic example for generating the Fibonacci sequence in Perl6 is given by the expression `1, 1, *+* ... *`, where he third term `*+*` is the rule for inductively generating the elements).

Comment: One important difference that maybe should be mentioned is that ranges will only go upwards when you iterate over them, i.e. `for 10..0 { }` will not run once. if you use `10...0` instead, it'll give you a descending sequence, as you might expect.